# Spivak's Definition of the Extended Integral: How do we determine that a function is NOT integrable?

Tags: integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Spivak defined the extended integral as follows: An open cover $\mathcal{O}$ of an open set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is admissible if each $U \in \mathcal{O}$ is contained in $A$. If $\Phi$ is a partition of unity subordinate to $\mathcal{O}$ and $f: A \rightarrow R$ is bounded in some open set around each point of $A$, and the set of discontinuities of $f$ is of measure 0, then we define $f$ to be integrable if $\sum_{\mathcal{\phi} \in \Phi} \int_A \mathcal{\phi} |f|$ converges, and $\int_A f = \sum_{\mathcal{\phi} \in \Phi} \int_A \mathcal{\phi} f$ .

Most similar questions about this definition are asking about the ambiguity of the definition: How can we define the integral $\int_A f $ in terms of $\int_A \mathcal{\phi} f$ when $A$ may not be a bounded set, which is the only thing we've defined integration for? My understanding is that each $\phi$ has compact support, and thus the integral on $A$ of $\phi f$ is only nonzero in this compact set, so it's not a problem.

My question is the opposite: when do we know that $f$ is **NOT** integrable under this definition? Spivak later shows that if $f$ is integrable, the specific partition of unity doesn't matter, the above sum will always be the same. However, he only defines integrability relative to one partition of unity. So, I would initially assume that $f$ is integrable if there exists any partition of unity $\Phi$ satisfying the above condition (since then the integral of $f$ on any partition of unity is the same as on $\Phi$.

However, question 3-38 in the same chapter gives a function $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is not integrable on $\mathbb{R}$, and asks for two partitions of unity $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ such that the sums

$\sum_{\phi \in \Phi} \int_A \phi f$ and $\sum_{\psi \in \Psi} \psi f$

both absolutely converge, but to different values. So, it seems that the absolute convergence of one sum isn't sufficient, but that all sums on different partitions of unity need to converge to the same value.

I can show that there exists a partition of unity on $\mathbb{R}$ such that the sum over that partition of unity does not converge absolutely. So then, is $f$ not integrable if "There exists a partition of unity $\Phi$, satisfying all the conditions, such that $\sum_{\phi \in \Phi} \int_A \phi f$ does not converge absolutely"? Meaning, there may be some partitions of unity where the sum does in fact converge absolutely, but as long as there is one where it does not, the function is not integrable?

Note that I'm not asking for a solution to Spivak 3-38 (in fact, I would not like one, we have a homework question very similar to it, and I would not like to cheat or spoil the answer for myself), I am specifically asking for clarification on the definition of integrability.